# LaunchSettings.json missing in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

[VS2019 web project 4.7.1 framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9zKJ.png)

Till Visual studio 2017, there was a file to store Environment variables "launchsettings.json"

using c# environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Name of variable") we can read environment variable values,

Recently I created a new project in VS2019 and there is no file by default as "launchsettings.json" and when I added JSON file manually c# code is not able to read those environment variables

Does anybody know where to store environment variables in VS2019?

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 ways to access the environment variable section.

You can add/change them through `launchsettings.json`.

[image]

Or you can right-click on the project and select `Properties`. Then you go under Debug tab and you will be able to change them.

[image]

Comment: This is not available with VS2019 :(

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 - Version 16.2.5

Comment: Putting a screenshot of what you have on the screen in the question will be helpful

Comment: Added web project link in my question at the top  - no debug tab + under properties no launchsettings.json file by default

Comment: It is because you have create a library project and not a web project.

Comment: @billybob What you are describing here works for .NET (Core), but not for .NET Framework apps.